# FB.ui : stream.publish - post to wall issue

Tags: facebook

When I click a link which calls following function...I get 
"Something went wrong. We're trying fix it as soon as possible".

It's been working for couple weeks, and has started behaving like this, for last week.

Did I change anything?, probably yes. But, the same code works on another non-production, test fb-app-settings!!

Here is the javascript.(There's no javascript error on the page)

I need help figuring out what's wrong or where to look! I've waiting couple days, but still same problem.

```
function publishReview() {
    var atch = {
        name: 'Raajneeti - Movie Review',
        href: 'http://www.moviereviewsindia.com/Movie.aspx/Details/Raajneeti',
        caption: '{*actor*} just revealed his taste of a movie',
        description: 'Write, Read and Share movie reviews just through your Facebook Account',
        media: [{ type: 'image', src: 'http://moviereviewsindia.com/Content/Images/logoround.png', href: 'http://www.moviereviewsindia.com'}]
    };

    FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'stream.publish',
            message: '3/5 - Multi-starrer raajneeti was good but not great, and a very good efforts from Prakash Jha. A lot happened in 3 hours. I recommend to hire ajay devgan for car wash. Nana patekar was rocking as usual in his unusual style. Take him out and your movie experience may deterior. Ranbeer got a nice role of ARJUN, and he was characterized nicely in the movie. I can\'t say whether he was that great in acting. Story was good enough, but don\'t expect total real life thingy there. ',
            attachment: atch,
            action_links: [
                { text: 'My Reviews', href: 'http://www.moviereviewsindia.com/User.aspx/Profile/1266802272' }
            ],
            href: 'http://www.moviereviewsindia.com/Movie.aspx/Details/Raajneeti',
            user_prompt_message: 'Share your thoughts about ' + 'Raajneeti - Movie Review'
        },
        function(response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                //success action

            } else {
                //failure action
            }

        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried with shorter FB.ui.message. And that worked. I wonder if there is any defined length limit for this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with shorter FB.ui.message. And that worked. I wonder if there is any defined length limit for this message.